# KVM Windows guest battery

Tags: debian, windows, virtual-machine, kvm, battery

I've installed KVM on a laptop with Debian 9. The guest is the latest Windows 10 (1803) with all updates and VirtIO drivers installed.

The issue is : Windows doesn't know he's on a laptop. Then, I don't see the battery icon and power management relative to a laptop usage.

How can I say to my guest he's on a laptop to get the battery informations ?

Comment: I think this is more a Win10 question than a Linux question...

Comment: I don't think because it's the virtualization which transfer the hardware information between host and guest. For example, with virtualbox, battery informations are transferred. So, the issue is certainly between KVM and Debian.

Comment: Your windows is in a virtual machine, not on your physical hardware. Some hardware can be passed through to the VM, but I'm not sure how the battery controller works in this regard.

Comment: I don't know too, but it could works because VirtualBox does. For other reasons, I have to use KVM, then I can't use VirtualBox to solve my problem.

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to superuser? As it would involve some cross-system configuration. 1. KVM pass through for the hardware 2. If this possibilty exists, you will need windows guest drivers for this interface, which I doubt exist out of the box. So it is actually a linux AND windows question. (As the tags also suggest)

Comment: This was cross-posted and should be closed - https://superuser.com/questions/1334662/kvm-windows-guest-battery.

Comment: I just had a brief look at `qemu-2.11.1` source code and it doesn't look like qemu (which is the emulation software actually used for KVM) does support this kind of feature—at least not when emulating `x86` hardware (OpenFirmware used on OpenPOWER machines seems to support this). AFAIK there is no virtio-device specification for a power supply either (and I recently had to read the spec for my day job).